# Serving over HTTPS using FastAPI

Tags: html, https, ssl-certificate, fastapi, uvicorn

I am trying to setup a web interface self hosted that uses HTTPS to protect the data the frontend sends to the backend. Everything is going to be hosted on the same ubuntu PC without internet access. I currently use uvicorn to deploy it.

I have a self signed ssl certificate (used openssl), with the following field : "subjectAltName=IP:127.0.0.1". The certificate seems to be ok since uvicorn seems fine with it, chrome and firefox too. I also have to specify https://... to access the interface. But the console shows : [warning message about mixed content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZCNr.png) so it seems like the problem comes from the fact that I do not have a domain name but only use the IP.

Adding "meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests"" in my HTML  gets rid of the warning but the network analyzer and python console still say that the header uses HTML 1.1 : [chrome network analyzer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlEpg.png)

I don't know how to fix it, because I don't know how to make my own DNS nor that I even can. And my web interface can't use a web hosting service to be hosted. I can't be mooving around login informations using HTTP.

Please help me fix it, thanks in advance.

Edit: To give a bit more context, the web interface and every service will be hosted on a pc in another country. Accessible via a VPN. The HTTPS is to protect any non-admin user from getting admin access by sniffing the REST requests. Even tho users are supposed to be knowned and trusted, it is still a risk I am not allowed to take.

Comment: If everything goes over localhost, I'm not sure what kind of situation you're envisioning where using https would provide any meaningful protection. However, since you're self-signing these certificates, you can create a host entry in `/etc/hosts` - for example `127.0.0.1 yourservice.local` and then create a certificate for `yourservice.local` - no need to involve DNS in any way, and you don't have to use the ip-address.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have tried creating an new certificate for a domain name and add it to /etc/hosts, it kinda worked. I can't access the website over https but chrome says the certificate isn't valid must be a typo somewhere. The entry for the domain was : subjectAltName=DNS:*.interface.sms,IP:127.0.0.1
Is it right ?

Comment: Tried creating a new certificate again and still isn't valid. I think its the subjectAltName that he doesn't like for some reason. Although it seem to follow the syntax it is supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need a domain then need a webservices like nginx , traefik , ... then set ssl for your service without it you can not set ssl for IP without domain

Comment: I have tried nginx and got a problem, I can't remember what was the problem but I only spent a few hours on it. I'll try again later when I have the time.
Thanks :)